# issue regarding tokenize.py

Tags: python

In python2.x tokenize() function has two arguments namely, 'readline' and 'tokeneater'. Second argument takes care of the output mechanism for tokenize() and is called once for each token. Now we know that in python3.x second argument 'tokeneater' is not there. How is output mechanism in python3.x being taken care of ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `tokenize` generates a stream of 5-tuples as its output, just as Python 2.x's `generate_tokens` does.